# Is it possible to have zip iterator (i.e. "zip" two iterators together) in foreach?

Tags: r, foreach, iterator

I have two objects of equal length (one is a list produced by parsing JSON, and another is a slice of multi-dimensional of an array), e.g.:

```
library(rjson)
library(foreach)
iter1<-iter( fromJSON(file=jsonfilename)$someJSONarray )
iter2<-iter( myarr, by="row" )
```

I need to be able to do the following:

```
out=foreach(x=zipiter(iter1,iter2),combine=list) %do%
{
    #Do stuff with elements from both iterators accessed by e.g. x[[1]] and x[[2]]
}
```

Is there any standard way of doing it (like in Python/C++ with boost Zip iterator)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is an `izip` function in the `itertools` package that does what you describe:

```
library(itertools)
out <- foreach(x=izip(iter1, iter2)) %do% {
    # x[[1]] contains a value from iter1
    # x[[2]] contains a value from iter2
}
```

But I prefer to specify multiple loop variables to `foreach`:

```
out <- foreach(x=iter1, y=iter2) %do% {
    # x contains a value from iter1
    # y contains a value from iter2
}
```

Both solutions iterate over values from the iterators in parallel.  If you want the two arguments in a list, then `izip` is more convenient.

Comment: Great! I assumed it was about iterating through compressed (zipped) file... I've just made my own izip iterator, and even named it `izipiter` to avoid name conflict with the `izip`... I feel so silly now. At least I've learned something about iterator construction. Thank you!

Comment: @AdamRyczkowski I named it after the izip function in the Python itertools package.  In fact, much of the iterators and foreach packages was copied from Python.  foreach attempts to copy Python list comprehensions, for example.

Answer (score 1):

This might not be exactly what you need, but hopefully it might at least get you on the right track:

```
library(foreach)

X = 1:10
Y = 11:20

out = foreach(x=t(data.frame(X, Y))) %do% {x[1,]*x[2,]}
```

Yes, this is weird, but it properly pairs up the data. If you pass in a dataframe, `foreach` iterates over the columns instead of the rows (this isn't entirely surprising since `lapply` does the same thing). So transposing the dataframe results in iteration over the rows, but then the `x` object is a column vector, so we need to index the rows instead of the columns like we'd expect.

Comment: Thank you. It certainly does the trick. It is not very much  straightforward, nor a documented trick, is it?

Comment: Glad I could help. You also might want to try experimenting with this strategy using other data structures like a matrix in case casting your data to a df slows down the operation. As you can see I only tried this out on 10 paired records, but I'm assuming you probably have significantly more data since you're using foreach and iterators.

Answer (score 0):

After Steve Weston's answer there is nothing really to add; I'd post my own working version of the zip iterator, so the people learning how to live with the iterators in R would benefit. The iterator is named `izipiter` to avoid name clash with the existing `izip` iterator.

```
library(foreach)    
izipiter<- function(iters)
{
    nextEl<-function()
    {
        tryCatch(
        {
        foreach(it=iters,.combine=list) %do%
            nextElem(it)
        }, error=function(e) {stop("StopIteration")})
    }
    obj<-list(nextElem=nextEl)
    class(obj) <- c('izipiter','abstractiter','iter')
    obj
}
```

And this is how to use it:

```
it1=iter(c(3,5,15))
it2=iter(list(x="a",y="b",z=c("one","two","three")))

myit=izipiter(iters=list(it1,it2))

foreach(it=myit) %do%
    print(it)
```